# How to get GPS data from Android phone to Debian?

Tags: linux, debian, android, smartphone

I want to use my phone as a GPS receiver on Debian. I can connect the phone via usbc and wifi, but I have no Bluetooth on the pc.
Anyone can explain how to get GPS data from the phone?
The best thing would be have it recognized as a GPS receiver

Answer (score 4):

### Requirements:

1. In PC, install adb package with `sudo apt install adb`. Or download it directly from [this link](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-linux.zip).
2. In Android, enable Developer options and USB debugging.
3. Connect Android with USB cable, run `adb devices` in terminal, allow USB debugging prompt in phone.

[image]

### Procedure:

1. In Android, enable GPS. Then open Settings > About Phone > tap five times on Kernel version > Single Item Test > GPS.
2. In PC, Open terminal in PC. Clear all previous log with `adb logcat -c`
3. To filter out the GPS logs only, run any of the command below:

   - For all GPS related logs: `adb logcat | grep -i gps`
   - For GPS tag: `adb logcat "*:S Gps_test_Activity"`

The output will show 1. Number of Satellites (num) 2. Satellite ID (prn) 3. Elevation 4. Azimuth. For further filtering, use grep, awk, sed tools.

Comment: Thank you. Will this make the output usable in other programs which require GPS?

Comment: @Kodeeo If a program need Latitude and Longitude the it has to be calculated from Azimuth and Elevation. Or use Location class from Android API.

Answer (score 0):

more alternatives:

- using the Geoclue service + [GeoclueShare app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.freedesktop.geoclueshare&hl=en)
- using the `gpsd` service + [BlueNMAE app](http://max.kellermann.name/projects/blue-nmea/)

see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501719/how-to-get-gps-data-from-android-phone)